# What current Android phones use an NFC controller from NXP?

Tags: android, nfc, cyanogenmod

I want to port an NFC card emulation app to a smartphone running CyanogenMod, but that seems to require a phone with an NFC controller from NXP.

Does anybody know some current phones that still have an NXP NFC controller?

Is NXP still selling NFC controllers?

Thanks,

Dawg

Answer (score 6):

Phones that have an NXP NFC chip:

- Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus and 2012 Nexus 7.
- All previous Samsung devices before the S4 (so Galaxy S2, S3, Note 1 & 2)
- Almost all HTC phones (One, One X, One X+, EVO 4G, Droid Incredible 4G)
- Motorola Droid Razr
- Sony Xperia models
- Acer Liquid E1 (although this doesn't have a secure element)

I've used the CyanogenMod NFC emulation on the Nexus S and it worked brilliantly.

Although you didn't ask for reference some ones that don't use NXP and use Broadcom chips instead are the Nexus 4, Galaxy S4, Nexus 10 & 2013 Nexus 7 Tablet.